# Send HTTP Basic-Auth header info while submitting pdf to webserver

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext

I'm looking for a sample as to how to send HTTP Basic-Auth header info as part of pdf submit via javascript.

I found the following sample javascript code from one of the iText pdf examples:

```
this.submitForm({
  cURL:"http://itextpdf.com:8080/book/request",
  cSubmitAs: "HTML"
});
```

Are there any other options to send HTTP username:password as part of the submitForm() method?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on using forms with PDFs, but from what I gather from the [API documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) (page 345) and the responses on [Adobe's help forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1261888?tstart=0) it doesn't look possible.

You may take a look into `Net.HTTP.request` though, that one does have an `oAuthenticate` argument (page 550 on the [API 8.1 documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) or [here](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?&accessible=true) for API 9.1) that would allow you to pass user and password for HTTP authentication or show a dialog where the user can type those in -- you can actually modify any HTTP header.

Performing a `POST` request that way with an appropriate `oRequest` would (probably) end up having the result you are looking for.

> **Note:** Just realised the PDF I was citing is from SDK 8.1, [SDK 9.1](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?&accessible=true) doesn't show any authentication parameter for the `submitForm` method either though.